# how to use wordpress own jquery in a plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am facing a small problems, which is, I use this `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` in my plugin that is default js of WordPress. I didn't a get a result, but if i use an external live js library like this :

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
 wp_register_script('jquerylbs', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquerylbs');
```

This is successfully connect and get a result.

*Note: My WordPress version is up to date..*

Comment: if you mean that `$` doesn't load, try using `jQuery` (e.g. `jQuery('body').length`)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your jquery scripts by following code

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );

    function add_scripts( ){
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
```

Comment: are you using jquery in wp-admin or in front ?

Answer (score 0):

Just enqueue your script with WordPress default `jQuery` dependency. Like below-

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts with WordPress default jQuery.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'you-script-handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', array('jquery'), 'your-script-version', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

It'll automatically use the WordPress default `jQuery`.